# Functional difference between serviceName and accountName in SecKeychainAddGenericPassword

Tags: ios, keychain

I am about to use `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword` to store a bunch of protected information in my ios-app, and all that I need is a 'safe' key-value store. By 'safe', I mean the information should not be easily tampered with. I am stuck at two different fields required here, namely `accountName` and `serviceName`.

From the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1398366-seckeychainaddgenericpassword, I am not able to figure out if there would be any functional difference between these two strings. The app is supposed to be used for a single user, and the information is supposed to be accessible through out the app. What should I be putting in `accountName` and `serviceName`? Would anything change if I swap the two?

Note: I understand the conceptual difference between the two, but if I do not have a username, how should (can) I split my 'key' to fill in both `accountName` and `serviceName`.

Comment: Are you sure `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword` is available on iOS? I thought it was just recently added to macOS. I thought you still had to use `SecItemAdd` on iOS (which is a pain, and I highly recommend using a wrapper instead of writing that code by hand).

Comment: Ohh .. yeah you are right, it is available only on macOS, I will have to use SecItemAdd. Thanks for answering anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just field labels. For the use you're describing, it's not relevant how you use them. You just need to know what you've done so you can search for the data. There's no requirement that you even use both.

Note that the only thing that is encrypted is the "data" (the password in this case). Anything you put in these fields is metadata that can be searched on. I often put the account and password together and store it as the data so that they're both encrypted. Then I just have a hard-coded "service" that I use to look up the record. Storing data in the account field is most useful if you have multiple accounts.